# How to improve PHP for loop?

Tags: php

I want to create array with random numbers. But whenever the for loop need to iterate ~100000, it gets really slow. Is there any way to optimize it or get rid of the loop to create the arrays?

```
for ($i=0; $i <15 ; $i++) {

    for ($j=0; $j <100000 ; $j++) { 
        $rand_feq[$i][$j]=(float) mt_rand() / (float) mt_getrandmax();
        $rand_severity[$i][$k]=(float) mt_rand() / (float) mt_getrandmax();
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't just going to be slow, it's going to end up as a massive memory hog. What's your actual use case for this?

Comment: Do you need 2 arrays or 30?

Comment: I need two matrix for example, 
$rand_feq[15][100000] and  $rand_severity[15][100000]

Comment: any reason you're not using `rand` instead of `mt_rand`?

Comment: yes, i have used mt_srand(2) , mt_rand has been used to make the random numbers to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($j=0; $j <100000 ; $j++) { 
       $rand_feq[$i][$j]=(float) mt_rand() / (float) mt_getrandmax();
       $rand_severity[$i][$j]=(float) mt_rand() / (float) mt_getrandmax();
}
```

you can do both initialization inside same `for loop`